# Convertir consulta sql en linq sin que las tablas tenglas primarykey y forekey

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Amigos tengo un sistema en el que tengo que migrar un archivo excel, hasta aqui no hay problema,
de ahi tengo que hacer una relacion con una tabla de mi sistema en la que los unicos campos posibles de identificar o de relacionar es el RF, por lo que solicito apoyo para poder convertir la siguiente consulta a linq.

```
SELECT       YEAR(MtoContrato.FechaTerminacion) AS anio, MtoProveedor.RazonSocial,
         COUNT(MtoContrato.NoContrato) AS NoContrato,
         SUM(MtoContrato.MontoContrato) AS MontoMaximo
FROM            MtoContrato LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     MtoProveedor ON dbo.MtoContrato.RfcProveedor = MtoProveedor.RfcProveedor
WHERE        (YEAR(MtoContrato.FechaTerminacion) = 2019)                         
GROUP BY MtoProveedor.RazonSocial, MtoContrato.FechaTerminacion
ORDER BY anio DESC, MontoMaximo DESC
```

les comento el año puede variar es decir necesito que se una variable.

Saludos y muchas gracias,

Comment: Publica los modelos de las entidades en el query para que sea mas facil dar una respuesta.

Comment: Dado que la consulta `SQL` tiene muchas funciones y un `JOIN` podrías considerar crear un procedimiento y llamarlo desde `C#`, así no sobrecargas tu código con una consulta que puedes obtener de forma más rápida mediante sp

Comment: que tal amigo podrias darme un ejemplo de como implementarlo y de como llamar al sp desde c# con entityframework.